# Advanced tables does not work with memoir class, why?

Tags: tables, memoir

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{report Advanced Tables}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{table}[b]
\ra{1}
\begin{adjustbox}
\small
\begin{tabular}{c{}ccc{}ccc}\toprule 
&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Geometric Arguements} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Line Arguments} \\
\hline
$A_b$ & & $(B/C)_{circle}$  & $(D/E)_{Rect}$  & $(F/G)_{square}$ & & $H_{line}$ & $h_s/h_{avg}$ & $G_a/n_{nor}$ \\ \hline
$P_{p}/T_{t} = 4.15$ \\
2.56  && 3.56  & 7.89   & 9.97  && 4.52 & 8.80  & 80.78 \\
$P_{p}/T_{t} = 5.15$ \\
56.5    && 3.09 & 1.45  & 3.56  && 2.12 & 1.72  & 59.94 \\ 
77.1    && 8.89 & 1.96  & 4.60  && 1.47 & 1.74  & 90.45  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{\label{tab:table_one}report class advanced table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output of the code is as follows:

[image]

If the `\documentclass` is changed to `memoir` it says

```
Fatal error occured
```

and

no output of the PDF file is produced. Is it possible for anybody who could produce the same output in `memoir`?

Comment: Are you really running this code successfully with `report`? I get errors even with `report.cls`

Comment: Your table is ill composed, also are missing packages in preamble etc. Please correct your MWE, that it will works.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get the following error message: `LaTeX Error: Environment adjustbox undefined.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main error is caused by the missing required argument to `\begin{adjustbox}`. On the other hand, surrounding the table with

```
\begin{adjustbox}{}
<table>
\end{adjustbox}
```

does nothing, except localizing the font size change. But keeping it for future adjustments is not harmful.

You also had wrong `{}` in the argument to `tabular` and `&&` when it should be simply `&`.

Here's a fixed up version, using `siunitx` for better alignment of the numbers. I also fixed the textual subscripts to be in upright font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\section{report Advanced Tables}

\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{}
\small
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=2.2]
  *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Geometric Arguments} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Line Arguments} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
{$A_b$} &
  {$(B/C)_{\mathrm{circle}}$} &
  {$(D/E)_{\mathrm{Rect}}$} &
  {$(F/G)_{\mathrm{square}}$} &
  {$H_{\mathrm{line}}$} &
  {$h_s/h_{\mathrm{avg}}$} &
  {$G_a/n_{\mathrm{nor}}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{$P_{p}/T_{t} = \num{4.15}$} \\
2.56  & 3.56  & 7.89   & 9.97  & 4.52 & 8.80  & 80.78 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{$P_{p}/T_{t} = \num{5.15}$} \\
56.5    & 3.09 & 1.45  & 3.56  & 2.12 & 1.72  & 59.94 \\ 
77.1    & 8.89 & 1.96  & 4.60  & 1.47 & 1.74  & 90.45  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\caption{Report class advanced table\label{tab:table_one}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Christian Hupfer, Zarko, Mico and finally @egreg who gave my imitating successful table with memoir. Of course,  I thank you all of you for writing codes speding your golden time. I ticked all the three but it is taking only one. So I gave the credits to egreg which is my requirement table. After this I am using all the three tables and the credit should go equally to all. Please request the tex community to have a tick for more than one solutions. The green tick mark is for all of three. This made me confusion for hours.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any benefits of use of `adjustbox` (it as was provided in MWE, cause error) in your table, I comment it (for  possible future proper use).

After erasing all surplus ampersands and slightly "prettifying" of your table I got at memoir as document class the following result:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
        \usepackage[margin=1 in,showframe]{geometry}
        \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,multirow}
        \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

        \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Report Advanced Tables}
    \begin{table}[htb]\centering
\ra{1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
%\begin{adjustbox}{} %<-- added missing part 
\small
    \begin{tabular}{*{8}{>{$}c<{$}}}
    \toprule
\multirowcell{2}{P_{p}/T_{t}}
    &   \multirowcell{2}{A_b}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Geometric Arguments}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Line Arguments}                \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    &
        &  (B/C)_{circle}
            &   (D/E)_{Rect}
                &   (F/G)_{square}
                    &  H_{line}
                        & h_s/h_{avg}
                            & G_a/n_{nor}                       \\
    \midrule
4.15    & 2.56  & 3.56  & 7.89  & 9.97  & 4.52  & 8.80  & 80.78 \\
5.15    & 56.5  & 3.09  & 1.45  & 3.56  & 2.12  & 1.72  & 59.94 \\
        & 77.1  & 8.89  & 1.96  & 4.60  & 1.47  & 1.74  & 90.45 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{report class advanced table}
    \label{tab:table_one}
    \end{table}
```

Between `geometry` parameters I add `showframes` for better seeing the width of table.

**Edit (1):**  After seeing Mico answer I recognize that I wrong decode table data :-( it actually has 8 columns instead of seven as I recognize from your MWE. Now I correct this and also add two packages: ˙makecell˙and `multirow`. Both I use to make column head for first two columns. I also enlarge column separation. by this the table width is almost equal to text width. Of course, more exact fitting to text with you obtain with use of  `tabularx` as show Mico in his answer.

If you like to have table width as text width, than the simplest solution is use `tabularx` table environment.

**Edit (2):** Regarding use of the `adjustbox` I corrected myself. If it is correctly used also work with `memoir` as elaborate egreg in his answer and pointed me in his comment. Now I also added missing packages `makecell` and `multirow`, which I use in my MWE

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get an error message about `\multirowcell` being an "undefined control sequence".

Comment: I believe that `memoir` is perfectly compatible with `adjustbox`. It's just that a required argument was missing.

Comment: @egreg, I so rarely  use the adjust box that I overlooked its wrong use here. I will correct my wrong statement about it and memoir. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that gets by without an `adjustbox` mechanism, and which compiles fine with both the `report` and the `memoir` document classes. It uses a `tabularx` environment to assure that the table takes up the full width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\section{Report Advanced Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} cc *{5}{C} c @{}}
\toprule 
$P_{p}/T_{t}$ & $A_b$
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Geometric Arguments} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Line Arguments} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
& & 
$(B/C)_{\textit{circle}}$  & $(D/E)_{\textit{Rect}}$  & $(F/G)_{\textit{square}}$ & 
$H_{\textit{line}}$ & $h_s/h_{\textit{avg}}$ & $G_a/n_{\textit{nor}}$ \\ 
\midrule
4.15 & 2.56 & 3.56 & 7.89 & 9.97 & 4.52 & 8.80 & 80.78 \\
\addlinespace
5.15 & 56.5 & 3.09 & 1.45 & 3.56 & 2.12 & 1.72 & 59.94 \\ 
     & 77.1 & 8.89 & 1.96 & 4.60 & 1.47 & 1.74 & 90.45 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{report class advanced table} \label{tab:table_one}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you better figured out OP  table code :-) than me. Now I need to correct my guessing, what it is in table ... Nice solution.